# Angular changing a select value to null based on other select change

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack, mean

i am trying to add a popup form using an ng-template which have multiple selects .on ngOnInit() i add all the values as null
some of these selects are shown based on the previous select value using ngif
the problem is that when i change the value the second select go away but its value still the same this is my code :

```
<div *ngIf="cosForm.value.customer=='617e7d83c68272eba7c36c13'">
    
    <div class="form-group text-right">
      <label class="col-form-label" for="service">customer</label>
      <select ng-model="selectedItem" class="form-control" placeholder="customer" autocomplete="customer"
        formControlName="customer" required
        [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.customer.errors, 'is-valid': f.customer.touched && !f.customer.errors }">
        <option *ngFor="let customer of myCustomers" value="{{customer._id}}">{{customer.name}}</option>
      </select>
      <div *ngIf="submitted && f['customer'].errors" class="invalid-feedback">
        <div *ngIf="f['customer'].errors.required">customer is required</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

i want when i change the first select value the second ng select value set to null
i tried to use

```
<select onChange="cosForm.value.customer=null"> </select>
```

on the first select but i didnt get any result

i wanted to use :<div *ngIf="cosForm.value.customer=='!617e7d83c68272eba7c36c13'">

but i couldn't figure out how to affect the value

BTW: even if i change the first select, without changing the second ,i think the second select value is automatically changed because my submit button change to invalid and it became valid only when i fill the second select

Comment: You could use a reactive form to do this the easier way and better way out. What are you trying to achieve here

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to invalidate another select based on one select then you can listen to changes in the first select tag with this

```js
form.controls.customer.valueChanges.subscribe(()=>{
  // Set the value of the second select to null here
  form.controls.secondSelect.reset()
  
})
```